# How to conditionally add query parameter to route in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I am using `vue-router` to redirect to a new URL after clicking on a button. I would like the router to only add a query parameter into the URL if the query parameter is actually filled. So if it is `null` it should **not** add the parameter.

Right now this is not working as expected. Have a look at the following code snippet (choose each of the options and click the button).

*(it seems you can't use routing on Stackoverflow so please also have a look at the snippet on JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/okfyxtsj/28/)*

```js
Vue.use(VueRouter);

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router: new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
  }),
  computed: {
   currentRoute () {
     return this.$route.fullPath
    }
  },
  data () {
   return {
     some: this.$route.query.some || null      
    }
  },
  template: '<div><select v-model="some"><option :value="null">Option (value = null) which leaves empty parameter in URL</option><option value="someParameter">Option (value = someParameter) which shows parameter with value in URL</option><option :value="[]">Option (value = []) which removes parameter from URL</option></select><br><button @click="redirect">Click me</button><br><br><div>Current Path: {{ currentRoute }}</div></div>',
  methods: {
   redirect () {
     this.$router.push({
        path: '/search',
        query: {
          some: this.some || null
        }
      })
    }
  },
  watch: {
    '$route.query': {
      handler(query) {
       this.some = this.$route.query.hasOwnProperty('some') ? this.$route.query.some : null
      },
    },
  },
  watchQuery: ['some']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-router/dist/vue-router.js"></script>


<div id="app"></div>
```

When `some` is `null` the parameter will still be added to the URL. When `some` is an empty array it will not be added to the URL.

I don't want to use an empty array as default value since the value should always be a string.

So how can I make sure the query parameter is only added to the new route if it contains a value other than `null`?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you're asking how to add the `query` object to the param passed to `$router.push` only if the `this.some` variable is truthy. https://jsfiddle.net/0bcd6gt2/

Comment: Thank you for your response and the snippet. I was hoping that there is a way without having to manually check each variable before adding it to the router.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a simple `if-else` or `ternary` construct. Also prefer computed property for `some` instead of watcher:

```
Vue.use(VueRouter);

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router: new VueRouter({
        mode: 'history'
    }),
    computed: {
        some() {
            return this.$route.query.some || null;
        }
    },
    data() {
        return {};
    },
    methods: {
        redirect() {
            const routeConfig = this.some
                ? { path: '/search', query: { search: this.some } }
                : { path: '/search' };

            this.$router.push(routeConfig);
        }
    },
    // Remaining config like template, watchers, etc.
});
```